# PHP generates new rand() after submitting

Tags: php, forms, if-statement, random, captcha

I've got a problem that (I think) more people got.
I generate a rand() in my PHP script, and if the form that I created submits, I don't want to create a new rand(), what's he actually doing right now.

### I DON'T want to...

- Set the value in a SESSION or COOKIE
- Set the data in a hidden input

Because of..
Security reasons (it's a simple captcha)

Thanks.

Comment: You know that if you store it in a session field, the end user is not able to see it?

Comment: If you don't want a session or hidden input, then you can pass it along in the query string or store / retrieve it from a database. If you don't store it somewhere, then you can't expect PHP to remember it, can you...

Comment: @Actorclavilis I know, but yeah, I'd like to get another way for this (without database usage and session)

Comment: You're rejecting all the methods used for keeping values between scripts. it's like asking for a way to keep dry in the rain, but without using an umbrella or raincoat.

Comment: Why don't you look at how other captcha scripts work? You think you're the first to worry about security there?

Comment: I decided to put the data simply in a session. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no other way than saving it in a session. It is very secure and easy to obtain. You can even unset the session after you're done verifying it!

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know that you can unset it so easy!